# How to fix the poor quality of the colored emojis?

Tags: qt, rendering, emoji, qt-quick

I'm using Qt Quick to create an application which shows messages. Some of them contain emojis, and this is an important feature the application should support. These emojis must be colored, drawing them in black&white isn't enough.

I can use the colored emojis in my text without problems, by using the "Segoe UI Emoji" font family. However they appear jagged, their rendering quality is very poor, and unfortunately this isn't acceptable for my clients. This way I cannot distribute my application.

However, I tried all the possible options I know to increase the drawing quality, none of them have improved anything.

Here is a sample of the code I use in my qml files:

```css
Text
{
    id: itemTextID
    width: parent.width - 20
    text: "I don't know  I forgot!"
    renderType: Text.NativeRendering
    textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
    font.family: "Segoe UI Emoji"
    font.pixelSize: 18
    anchors.margins: 10
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.top: parent.top
    color: "#101010"
}
```

Below is a screenshot of the rendering I get, and what I expect:

[image: Qt emojis rendering sample]

The black&white version seem to not present this issue. I also tried to change the OpenGL configuration (all I known), but no way.

So is there a way to improve the colored emojis rendering quality? If yes, what should I do to achieve that?

Comment: What is the version of Qt5 and what is your OS ?, I do not reproduce your problem in Linux with Qt 5.13.1

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.13.0 with Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 Professional, 64 bit (version 1809)

Comment: I feel this is more a question for the Qt interest mailing list and/or for the support if you have a commercial license

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't a such license, I'm using Qt under the GPL v3 terms

Comment: I would think this is a matter of the installed emoji font, maybe try with adding your own explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to fix this issue. The following line must be added to the Text block:

```css
font.hintingPreference: Font.PreferNoHinting
```

The complete answer can be found on the following post:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/113454/poor-quality-colored-emojis-how-to-fix-that